# VSCode automatically starts up some debugging inspector in the built-in terminal ever since 1.47.0 update

Tags: vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Ever since the update yesterday to `1.47.0`, when VSCode starts up, it gives me this output in the terminal (without a subsequent prompt which would allow me to type):

```js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55430/f3f20387-0605-4a39-b807-77f02bea362f
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

My otherwise usual procedure has been that I:

1. Use WSL to navigate to the project directory I want to open, and the type `code .`
2. I would then start up my server within the VSCode terminal (bash) by typing `npm run serve` (package.json has `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve"`).

However, I obviously can't do this now that there's some debugger and inspector continuously running? Here's a screenshot showing my blank `launch.json` and the terminal:

[image: debugger showing instead of command prompt]

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I have no idea what has gone wrong, but it only seems to happen with this particular project which I'm opening with `code .`

---

### UPDATE

So I tried some more things.

1. I ran `cp -rf testsite testfrontend` within WSL
2. and then in the copied directory I deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
3. I subsequently ran `npm install`
4. I then started VSCode by running `code .` in the directory of the copied project within WSL

When vscode came up, the terminal wasn't showing. When I showed it (ctrl+`), the following lines ran automatically on their own:

[image: vscode terminal startup]

5. Then I ran `npm run serve`, and the following happened:
   [image: stuck]
6. And with this message in the Debugger Console tab:
   [image: error]

I should mention that I don't get this error or any of the other aforementioned issues when I run `npm run serve` directly from WSL. I also don't get the aforementioned issues if I click the green `WSL: Ubuntu` button at the bottom left and then choose `Remote-WSL: New Window` and then run `npm run serve`:
[image: new window]

Answer (score 4):

I ended up solving this by running the project from WSL with `code --disable-extensions .` and ignoring the subsequent error messages. I then shutdown VSCode and ran it normally with `code .`, and it started working normally again as it did in the past. No clue why this worked. I also posted the Issue on [VSCode's official GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102240), where someone replied:

> You can fix this for the moment by setting `debug.node.autoAttach` to `disabled`, then reloading the window / reopening the terminal.

Hope this helps someone.